# how to create code for sanity testing auto screen capture?

Tags: capture, sanity

Fast screenshot

How to easily take screenshot of my screen in windows 10?

I would like to have option to select a part of my screen to take the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>IGG</groupId>
  <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>sample</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>AsposeJavaAPI</id>
    <name>Aspose Java API</name>
    <url>https://repository.aspose.com/repo/</url>
</repository>
<repository>
<id>Central Repositroy</id>
<url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.1stleg</groupId>
    <artifactId>jnativehook</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspose-ocr</artifactId>
    <version>17.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.1stleg</groupId>
    <artifactId>jnativehook</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sanity.java

package sanity;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Sanity {
   private JFrame mainFrame;
   private JLabel headerLabel;
   private JLabel statusLabel;
   private JPanel controlPanel;

   public Sanity(){
      prepareGUI();
   }
   public static void GUI(String[] args){
      Sanity  swingListenerDemo = new Sanity();  
      swingListenerDemo.showKeyListenerDemo();
   }
   private void prepareGUI(){
      mainFrame = new JFrame("Java SWING Examples");
      mainFrame.setSize(400,400);
      mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

      headerLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER );
      statusLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);        
      statusLabel.setSize(350,100);
      
      mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
            System.exit(0);
         }        
      });    
      controlPanel = new JPanel();
      controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
      mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
      mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
   }
   private JTextField textField;
   private void showKeyListenerDemo(){
      headerLabel.setText("Listener in action: KeyListener");      
      textField  = new JTextField(10);
      textField.addKeyListener(new CustomKeyListener());
      JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
      
      okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
         
         {
            try {
                p2.saveDoc();
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } 
            
            // need to write the code
         }
      });
      controlPanel.add(textField);
      controlPanel.add(okButton);    
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
   }
   class CustomKeyListener implements KeyListener{
      public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
      }
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            statusLabel.setText("Entered text: " + textField.getText());
         }
      }
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
      }   
   }
}
```